# Are these extra Index fields needed?

Tags: mysql, index, select

I've designed a table as below for users who register a quiz:

```
CREATE TABLE `registered_quiz` (
 `rq_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `user_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `iq_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 `is_registered` char(0) DEFAULT NULL,
 `delivered` char(0) DEFAULT NULL,
 `final_point` float NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `total_rank` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 PRIMARY KEY (`rq_id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `user_id_2` (`user_id`,`iq_id`),
 KEY `user_id` (`user_id`),
 KEY `iq_id` (`iq_id`),
 KEY `date` (`date`),
 CONSTRAINT `registered_quiz_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`iq_id`) REFERENCES `inja_quiz` (`iq_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
 CONSTRAINT `registered_quiz_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `karbar` (`user_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

And I have a query as below:

```
SELECT final_point,total_rank,rq_id FROM registered_quiz WHERE user_id=1111 AND final_point<>0 AND total_rank<>0
```

1. Do I need the part  KEY `user_id` (`user_id`) ?

   I was wondering if  UNIQUE KEY `user_id_2` (`user_id`,`iq_id`) would be enough!
2. Do I have to index `final_point` and `total_rank` to get faster select results just because they are in the where clause?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, your index on `KEY user_id (user_id)` is redundant, since you have the index on `UNIQUE KEY user_id_2 (user_id,iq_id)` and `user_id` is the left-most prefix.

Second, you won't need to index `final_point` and `total_rank` because the mysql optimizer would  ignore the `<>0` portions, and scan the entire index based on `user_id`.

It is worth pointing out (even if it wasn't part of the question), that you must retain the index `KEY iq_id (iq_id)` because of the foreign key. If you don't have that index, the foreign key would create one exactly the same.

> in the referenced table, there must be an index where the referenced columns are listed as the first columns in the same order. [[src]](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html)

Comment: Just wanted to ask, should the WHERE clause for final_point and total_rank be any number (not <>0), an index on these will help?

Comment: If the WHERE were constants, it would still depend on the size of the table and what cardinality of the values in the columns. Even on a 100mil row table, I'd say an index just on `user_id` would suffice. You don't want too many indexes: affects write performance and, for innodb, greatly increases the storage size of the table's .ibd file (if you have the `innodb_file_per_table` option turned on)

Comment: Actually I just used <>0 for demonstration purposes, it is variable inside my app.

Answer (score 2):

Provided you have an index on `user_id` (or a compound index with `user_id` as the first column) and a user does not have to many rows, you don't have to index `final_point` and `total_rank`.

Comment: +dezso Do you think:   KEY `user_id` (`user_id`) is redundant?

Comment: @john.locke: it seem like that.  I found this reading very useful: http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/where-clause/the-equals-operator/concatenated-keys